# is there any way i can retrieve current gps coordinates using only an android service

Tags: android, gps, android-service, coordinates

i have to create an android service which needs to get the current G P S coordinates and display a toast through a timer with an interval of every minute. i cant seem to get the coordinates unless i send it manually through the emulator control. i already have a service that runs a timer every minute to display the toast "hello". but i haven't come across any solutions so far.

```
public static final long NOTIFY_INTERVAL = 60 * 1000; // 60 seconds
// run on another Thread to avoid crash
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
// timer handling
private Timer mTimer = null;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // cancel if already existed
    if(mTimer != null) {
        mTimer.cancel();
    } else {
        // recreate new
        mTimer = new Timer();
    }
    // schedule task
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 0, NOTIFY_INTERVAL);
}

class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // run on another thread
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // display toast
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hello",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: are you using emulator?

Comment: You need a real device to get current lat, lng.

Comment: yes, as @sunit said, you need a real device, on emulator what you enter shall be your coordinates. So better try on some device!

Comment: i did use a real device but when i use it, i'm not even able to send the lat, long coordinates through the emulator controls. so when i run my service. basically nothing happens :/ @sunit

Comment: you get real lat, long on your device, So what is the need to do that. And you can not send lat, long coordinates through the emulator controls to your real device.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

It explains how to get the current location on a device.